# Visualizing the elements of this basis:

Tags: general-topology

$\mathcal{B}$ $=$ { $B : 0\in B, B \subset \mathbb{R} $ } $\cup$ { $B:0\notin B, B \subset (\mathbb{R-Q})$}

I had a very fundamental doubt: will {$0$} always be a subset of any basis element?

Can someone give examples of the basis elements for better visualization?

According to Munkres: For a collection to be a basis, it needs to satisfy 2 properties, Does This collection qualify to be a basis for a topology $\tau$ on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: A basis for $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology, yes?

Comment: No, I mean that does it satisfy the 2 properties to be a valid basis. Never mind, I'll edit the question.

Comment: A basis of *what*?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I just edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An element of $\mathcal{B}$ is one of the following:

- An arbitrary subset $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ containing $0$ e.g. $(-1, 2]$ or $\{0\}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$
- An arbitrary subset of the irrationals $A$ i.e. $A$ is equal to $C \cap (\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q})$ where $C$ is some arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{R}$. e.g. $(14, 21) \cap (\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q})$

---

$\{0\}$ will not always be a subset of a basis element. Take

$$(14, 21) \cap (\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}) \in \{B: 0 \not\in B, B \subseteq (\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q})$$

It does not contain $0$ since $0 \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: From the definition of the collection $\mathcal{B}$, it seems to me that $C \cap \mathbb{R-Q}$ can not be expressed as the union of the 2 collections which make up $\mathcal{B}$ . Am I perceiving the Definition wrong?

Comment: the part before the union( in the definition of $\mathcal{B}$) says that zero should always be a part of it. which means $B$ can't be written as $\emptyset \cup (C \cup R)$.

Comment: That's true - it cannot. How does that matter though? $\\mathcal{B}$ is simply the set which is the union of the two sets I have described above. Maybe you have a misconception about what a basis of a topology is?

Comment: For an element to be in $\mathcal{B}$, it does not have to be written as the union of elements in the two collection. Any element of the topology, for which $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis needs to be writable as the union of elements in $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The base has two "types" of sets in it (that's what the union comes down to): all subsets of the reals that contain $0$, so in particular $\{0\}$ itself (so $0$ is an isolated point, an open set by itself) and also all sets that consist only of irrational points (which automatically implies $0$ is not in it, as it's rational). So all $\{r\}$ where $r$ is irrational are also open and thus isolated.

If $q \neq 0$ and rational then what basic open sets can contain $q$? not the second irrationals only type, and the first type only if $0$ is in it too, like $\{0,q\}$. So $q \in \overline{\{0\}}$ for any $q \in \Bbb Q$. The set $\Bbb R\setminus \{0\}$ is a discrete set in the subspace topology by the above considerations.

A "weird" topology indeed.

Answer (score 0):

The condition $\{B:0\notin B, B\subset(\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q)\}$ is redundant,  because $0\in\Bbb Q$.

$0$ certainly doesn't have to be in every basis element,  if you're talking about the basis for a topology.

This is a basis for a topology on $\Bbb R$,   because any finite intersection of elements of $\mathcal B$ can be written as a union of elements of $\mathcal B$. That's because such an intersection consists in arbitrary sets of irrationals or arbitrary sets containing zero (or a union thereof), which,  by definition,  are elements of $\mathcal B$ again.

Also,  $\mathcal B$ covers $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I have edited.